# CoreData is adding data again and again in to database

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have implemented core data stuff in APPDelegate and created a new class and getting data from JSON and NSURLConnection didfinishloading i am storing the data in to core data using fast enumeration it is working good and displaying in tableview with nsfetch request but the problem is every time i launch the application it is again and again storing the data in to sqlite file why is it happening the methods are below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.customCellClass = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (self.customCellClass == nil)
    {
        self.customCellClass = [[CellCustom alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    self.customCellClass.nameLabel.text = [_myArray[indexPath.row] name];// label
    self.customCellClass.cityLabel.text = [_myArray[indexPath.row] regions]; // label
    self.customCellClass.detailLabel.text = [_myArray[indexPath.row] summary]; //label
 return self.customCellClass;

}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    arrayData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication ]delegate];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSString * name ;
    NSString * summary;
    NSString * region;


    for (NSDictionary * dic in arrayData) {
        name = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        summary = [dic objectForKey:@"summary"];
        region = [dic objectForKey:@"region"];

        Discount * d = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Discount" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        d.name = name;
        d.summary = summary;
        d.regions = region;   
    }
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Getting error while saving data");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    [listTableView reloadData];
}
```

and the appdelegate methods are just common as every one gives
some one give me solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this observer and check whether it is called at the first start.

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(dataDidSave)
                              name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                  object:context];
-(void)dataDidSave
{
self.myArray = // get data from data base
[listTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74574/discussion-on-answer-by-vladz-coredata-is-adding-data-again-and-again-in-to-data).

Answer (score 1):

Because when you start the application you download and save the data again. Do check for the availability of such data in the database.
Or download data only at first launching.

Comment: The easiest way (if the data must be loaded once)

At launching:
if (![[NSUserdefaults standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alreadyLoaded"]) {
[self loadData];
[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"alreadyLoaded"];
}

Comment: Or, the second way. You may check on exist current object in data base,before you will save.

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Discount" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", [dic objectForKey:@"name"]];
[request setPredicate:predicate]; 

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (results.count==0){
save data in database
}

Comment: @ViadZ thanks for this solution i completed with this solution now i have to update the data in coredata with latest update time which is coming from the JSON how can i do that

Comment: How can i check with the last update time where time is coming from the server

Comment: You may add attribute lastUpdateDate to Discount entity, and check this date before save. Or save last date in NSUserDefaults
NSDate *lastDate =[ [NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastUpdateDate"];
if ([lastDate compare:newDate]== NSOrderedAscending) {
//save new date
//update lastDate in userDefaults
}

Comment: i will check and one more thing the first install and launch of the application data i first time it is downloading and storing to core data but it is not showing in the tableview but in the second launch it is showing why is this how can we solve this

Comment: Call [tableView reloadData] After saving the data. This is must resolve this problem.

Comment: No it is not coming in the first install and launch application data is downloading and storing to the Core data but it is not displaying but in the second launch it is showing and is there a way that data while downloading and saving to core data in the same time it has to show in the tableview

Comment: i heard about the NSUrlSession is this helps

Comment: where should i give reload data i given in connectiondidfinishloading but no change

Comment: Maybe you generate _myArray (get data from data base), before the data is saved. 
Do somethings this
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
//save data

self.myArray = [self getData]; // get saved data from data base
//and then
[listTableView reloadDta];
}

try do this.

Comment: getData is not coming self.myArray = [self getData];  like this

Comment: i mean you must load data from data base in this line. Try do it, and print in console NSLog(@"My array = %@",self.myArray); 
And then look what will happen. Need to know whether there is data.

Comment: Okay i checked it in the first install there is no data storing in to the array but in the second launch it is storing and printing the data it has stored that means the mistake i am doing is array

Comment: mistake is identified and now where i have do change with the array

Comment: the first launch there is no data but in the second launch there is data in array